# ASP.NET MVC best practices for view models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, expressiveannotations

I have a view model that has a property that I use for validation via `ExpressiveAnnotations`.

```
using ExpressiveAnnotations.Attributes;

public class SampleViewModel
{
    ...

    [AssertThat("IsCompliant == true", ErrorMessage = "Not compliant.")]
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }

    [AssertThat("IsCompliant == true", ErrorMessage = "Not compliant.")]
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }

    public bool IsCompliant
    {
        get
        {
            // Server-side logic that queries database.
            return SampleQueryRepository.IsCompliant(PropertyA, PropertyB);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this bad practice? Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Keep ViewModel be ViewModel, otherwise you'd one day be writing complicated logics in viewmodels. It also doesn't make sense that `IsCompliant` is being checked on every other property. It also means you're querying every time anyone access `IsCompliant`, be it your code or json serializers or mappers.

Comment: @teamol can you provide an answer showing a better way? Thanks.

Comment: It really depends on your project structure. One common structure I use is `Controller-Service-Repository`, and since it's service that can access repository, if any kind of validation needs database, then it happens in services. So you'd need to consider which classes can access data and handles business logics.